# Antonym von »übergut«

Tags: single-word-request

Wie lautet das Antonym von »übergut« (umg. »die Pizza war übergut|«)

- überschlecht?
- unterschlecht?
- (es gibt keins, welches auf *-schlecht* endet)

Comment: Ist *übergut* nicht ohnehin nur *überragend* oder *überwältigend* für Mundfaule? Ich schlage dann *unterkriechend* vor.

Comment: Übergut ist mal ein grottenschlechtes Wort und gehört doppelverbannt. SCNR - Wo kommt das Wort denn vor?

Comment: @Thomas Was ist so schlecht im Wort? Ich will es nicht schriftlich verwenden. Eigentlich ist mein tatsächliches Interesse zu wissen, wie man die *über-* Steigerung pauschal umkehrt. Es kam in einem Abendessensgespräch vor, wo jemand erstmals sagte: „die Pizza in XY war gut, aber diese war echt gut...“ um zuletzt sich zu korrigieren... „übergut“

Comment: Was ist schlecht an: gut, besser, am besten. Übergut ist. m.E. eine blöde Steigerungsform und habe ich auch wirklich seltenst gehört. Eine allgemeine Antonymisierungsregel gibt es wahrscheinlich nicht. Aber nimm meine Kritik nicht so ernst. PS: Vlt. liegt es auch am bescheuerten Unternehmen Uber. Im Englischen kommt jetzt ständig dieses vom Deutschen abgeleitete Uber vor.

Comment: Das Wort '_übergut_' kommt vor, leider. Das Adjektiv '_gut_' eignet sich aufgrund seiner Undifferenziertheit nicht gut für bestimmte Arten von Graduierungen, man würde ja z.B. auch nicht sagen 'das Essen war überlecker' oder '_die Jacke ist überschick_'. Für ein '_mehr als_' gibt es bereits '_super-, hyper-, mega-_', solche Bildungen unterliegen jedoch der Mode und können altmodisch werden. Für mich ist das Wort eine Gelegenheitsbildung und ein Umschreibungsversuch für etwas Gemeintes mit dem Unterton 'leider fällt mir gerade nichts Vernünftiges ein, ich weiß, dass das kein gutes Deutsch ist.'

Comment: Der Online-Duden führt 7 Bedeutungen für das Präfix _über-_ auf: [link](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueber_). Bedeutung 3 ist: "drückt in Bildungen mit Adjektiven (...) aus, dass das übliche Maß überschritten wird, dass etwas zu sehr ausgeprägt ist." Es muss dann so etwas wie 'zuviel des Guten' bezogen auf ein Standardmaß geben, bei _pünktlich_ als Standard etwa + - 5 Min. _Überpünktlich_ wäre 'auf die Sekunde genau'. _Übersensibel_ wäre 'von nicht nachvollziehbarer übertriebener Empfindlichkeit' usw. Gibt es für eine _gute_ Pizza ein Standardmaß? Ist _übergut_ auch 'übertrieben gut'?

Comment: @RalfJoerres Ja, zum Beispiel, dass nicht aufhören kann, die zu essen.

Comment: @ c.p. _Übersensibel_ heißt 'so sensibel, wie jemand besser nicht sein sollte'. _Überpünktlich_ heißt (auch) 'auf unangenehme Weise pedantisch pünktlich'. _Sich überanstrengen_ heißt 'sich so sehr anstrengen, dass man krank wird'. Ein _überbelichtetes_ Foto ist zu hell und nicht zu gebrauchen. Ein _überhitzter_ Motor geht kaputt. _Übereilt_ ist unüberlegt und vorschnell. _Übergroße_ Kleidung passt den allermeisten Menschen nicht. Eine _übergute_ Pizza ist aber nicht 'zu gut, so dass einem davon beinahe schlecht wird'. Es fehlt das negative Element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO ist das Antonym zu "[übergut](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=uebergut)" "überschlecht". ([Eintrag im DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=ueberschlecht))

Über ist die Steigerung des nachfolgenden Begriffs. Dies auch umzukehren würde den Begriff wieder abschwächen. Das Wort wäre zusammengesetzt also nicht der genaue Gegensatz.

Ähnlich verhält es sich wenn man die Vorsilbe "super" nutzt. Da würde man auch "supergut" vs "superschlecht" nutzen und nicht "supergut" vs "subschlecht"

Comment: Guter Vorschlag, zumal _überschlecht_ als okkasionell gebildetes Adjektiv - quasi als Wegwerf-Adjektiv - sich ebenso danebengegangen anhört wie _übergut_. Ich will damit sagen: Die beiden befinden sich auf einer einander entsprechenden Qualitäts- und damit auch Intensitätsstufe.

Answer (score 9):

Spontan fällt mir da

> [grot­ten­schlecht](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/grottenschlecht)

ein.

»sauschlecht« habe ich auch schon gehört.

Comment: Für mich wäre die Frage, ob man von '_grottenschlecht_' (ugs.) bzw. '_unteriridisch_' (ugs.) oder '_unter aller Kanone_' (veraltend, ugs.) ins Antonym zurückgespiegelt nicht eher bei '_zum Niederkien_' (gehoben), '_allererste Sahne_' (ugs,. möglicherweise veraltend), '_vom Feinsten_' (ugs.), '_hammergeil / megacool_' (jugendspr., veraltend?) oder ähnlichem herauskäme als bei einem relativ vermurksten '_übergut_'. Es mag jedoch sein, dass ein '_übergut_' sich in speziellen Szenen als Jargon etabliert hat. Weiß wer was dazu?